# Drawing a grid on a PictureBox

Tags: c#

I am currently working with a pictureBox. I am having difficulties drawing a grid over the picture box that is approximately the size of 2 x 2 squares. Now the code below is only giving me a line drawn across. How can I proplery draw a full grid on top of the pictureBox?

**CODE:**

```
private Graphics g1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        g1 = Graphics.FromImage(this.pictureBox1.Image);
        Pen gridPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        g1.DrawLine(gridPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);

    }
```

This what I would like to accomplish:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this question: 
[Efficiently draw a grid in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753519/efficiently-draw-a-grid-in-windows-forms)

Here is the gist of it:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int numOfCells = 200;
            int cellSize = 5;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

            for (int y = 0; y < numOfCells; ++y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, 0, y * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize, y * cellSize);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < numOfCells; ++x)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize);
            }
        }
```

Customize accordingly

Comment: +1 Thank you! this is in reference to the game of life. But I am not sure why or how you use `Form1_Paint` I thougth it will be inside the event `pictureBox` ? I am fairly new to C# and your help will be appreciated.

Comment: This should be the picture box's paint event. My apologies

Comment: Alright, thank you. I am getting no grids at all to appear. But the code has no error either. So i am not sure whats the issue.

Comment: hmmm. did you hook up the pictureBox paint event?

Comment: When i click on the pictureBox it gives me the `pictureBox_Click` event, so i dicided to copy/paste your code to hook up the event `pictureBox_Paint` but maybe that is the issue. How do i call that event `pictureBox_Paint` properly?

Comment: ah yes this is the issue. Click once on the picture box and go to the properities window. You'll find a lightening bolt button and click on that. This will bring you to all of the possible events you can use. Scroll until you find paint and double click on that. Copy paste my code there

Comment: Perfect and Thank you, I will accept this answer. One extra question: I was trying to make the cell size 2 x 2, How can i change the size propreties from your code to get this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17512/discussion-between-mikeb-and-charliecodex23)

Comment: I think you forgot about plotting the solid blue cells.

Answer (score 3):

MikeB's accepted answer is, of course, correct, but the OP was still confused and people are still seeing this, so I am adding a clarifying answer (yes, 8 years later).

Mike's method

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

is a standalone method that needs to be called at the right time. To make this happen, you need to register it with the OnPaint event dispatcher, so it will be called whenever OnPaint event occurs.  To do this you would put the following line into some handy place such as in the constructor of your class:

```
OnPaint += pictureBox1_Paint;
```

This approach is OK, but if you get to where you really need drawing performance it will hurt you, because it costs extra for the PaintEventArgs to be constructed and passed to you.  A better approach is to override the OnPaint method of the parent class and put your drawing code directly in the OnPaint method. That way you don't have to hook up any event handlers and it runs faster. The code looks almost the same:

```
protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int numOfCells = 200;
            int cellSize = 5;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

            for (int y = 0; y < numOfCells; ++y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, 0, y * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize, y * cellSize);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < numOfCells; ++x)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize);
            }
        }
```

One final suggestion: it is almost never a good idea to do drawing in a PictureBox control. A lot of people do it, but not many experts would do it that way. They were not designed to be a drawing canvas -- they just inherit the same functionality that all forms-based controls have -- and they add complexity and slow you down without adding any useful functionality at all. You will be happier if you get rid of the pictureboxes and just draw directly on the form or panel that was holding your picture box.